# Let $x_n,n \geq0$ a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+3}-3x_{n+2}+3x_{n+1}-x_{n})=2$ Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n^3}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n,n \geq0$ a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+3}-3x_{n+2}+3x_{n+1}-x_{n})=2$

Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n^3}$.

I know that $x_n$ is not convergent because if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = l$ then $l-3l+3l-l=0$ not 2 so it must be divergent.

Also the form of the first limit resembles the coefficients of $(a-b)^3$, but i do not know what information to extract from this.

Any tips? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triple application of the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) shows that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{n^3} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{(n+1)^3-n^3} = \cdots = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+3}-3x_{n+2}+3x_{n+1}-x_{n}}{(n+3)^3-3(n+2)^3 + 3(n+1)^3 - n^3} 
$$
if the latter limit exists.

Now note that the last denominator simplifies to a constant.