# Convergence of a "strange" sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Given $x_n$ a sequence of real numbers, define a sequence $b_n = x_{n+2} - 2x_{n+1} + x_n.$ This particular sequence is named "raw differences of $x_n$" which is defined in general with: $f(x_n):= x_{n+1}-x_n.$ So, if we apply $f$ one more time we obtain $b_n$. Suppose now that $\lim$ of $b_n$ is $l$. Prove that lim of $x_n / n^2$ is $l/2.$

I tried to introduce some inequalities to estimate $|x_n / n^2 - l/2|$ but I didn't got anything "clean". The value of $l$ can be finite or infinite. It is possible to extend this problem in general for the k-differences?

Comment: Do you mean $a_n$ where you wrote $x_n?$ Or visa versa?

Comment: Generally a bad case to use lower case l as a variable in plain text - it looks too similar to $1.$

Comment: Yess my bad that is x_n not a_n or visa versa

Comment: Also, the notation $f(x_n)$ is really the wrong notation. $f$ is a function of the whole sequence, and returns a sequence. So it might be written $f(x)_n=x_{n+1}-x_n.$

Comment: Apply the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz–Cesàro_theorem), twice. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4113492/42969 for a similar problem.

Comment: "This is a particular sequence because its name is "raw differences of $x_n$" which is defined in general with : $f(x_n):= x_{n+1}-x_n.$ So if we apply f one more time we obtain $b_n.$" Maybe it's just me, but I don't know what all this means. Please clarify.

Comment: Should it perhaps be $b_n = x_{n+2} - 2x_{n+1} + x_n$? – Which is equal to $(x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}) - (x_{n+1} - x_n)$, i.e. the “second difference” of the sequence $(x_n)$.

Comment: That function f is called ( in this exercise book) "raw differences of terms of x_n and it is defined as I wrote. f(f(x_n)) is f(x_(n+1)) - f(x_n)

Comment: Thanks all for the advices :)

Comment: The definition of $b$ is wrong, if it is supposed to be repeated application of $f.$

Comment: Counterexample to original formulation ($b_n=x_{n+2}-2x_{n+1}-x_n)$: $x_0=x_1=1$ and $x_{n+2}=2x_{n+1}+x_n$ grows faster than the Fibonacci sequence.